# Replacing a word with numbers

Tags: javascript, encryption

I'm trying to take a word(ex. example) and replace its letters with numbers from an array using Javascript.

ex: 

The word would be "example"(7 letters) and the numbers would be [ 19, 14, 1, 11, 5 ]

So, "example" would become [ 19, 14 , 1, 11, 5, 19, 14].

I can't figure out how to do this with words longer than the array of numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Please make it clear that you are not dealing with a Caesar cipher.

Comment: what kind of krypto algorithm returns e = 19  and x = 14??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

```js
var word = "example";
var numbers = [19, 14, 1, 11, 5];
var newNumbers = [];
var t = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= word.length - 1; i++) {
  if (t == numbers.length) {
    t = 0;
  }
  newNumbers.push(numbers[t]);
  t += 1;
}


console.log(newNumbers);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/he8pchem/1/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%` operator to keep looping through your number array:

```js
var arr = [9, 5, 22, 4, 3]
var word = 'california'
var numWord = [];
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) numWord.push(arr[i % arr.length]);
console.log(numWord);
```